# How do I aggregate date in a nested json dictionary in a postgres function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

Say I have the following table test-table:

| city | store | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | 7-11 | jsonb_data |
| Boston | Gas Stat | jsonb_data |

Where the jsonb_data is formatted as the following:

```
{
  "paging": {
    "total-pages": 1,
    "pageSize": 100,
    "pageIndex": 1
  },
  "tickers": [
    {
      "count": "pudding",
      "data-points": [
        {
          "day": "2023-03-18",
          "value": "26.7"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "count": "cake",
      "data-points": [
        {
          "day": "2023-03-18"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "count": "soda",
      "data-points": [
        {
          "day": "2023-03-18"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "count": "chips",
      "data-points": [
        {
          "day": "2023-03-18"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "count": "soda_machine",
      "data-points": [
        {
          "day": "2023-03-18",
          "value": "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

how can I use a function that would take the row and return a flattened row instead as the following:

| city | store | pudding | cake | soda | chips | soda_machine | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | 7-11 | 26.7 | *null* | *null* | *null* | OK | 2023-03-18 |

I've been able to use ->'tickers' to get to the array of data but seem to not be able to make any headway there

Answer (score 0):

You will need to normalize the data by unnesting the array, then you can access each element, then with `GROUP BY` and `MAX()` to convert rows into columns.

`->>` Get JSON array element as text, this needed to show result

`->` Get JSON array element, we need this to access elements.

```
with cte as (
  select t.city, t.store,
       ui.data ->> 'count' as count,
       ui.data -> 'data-points'->0->>'day' as day,
       ui.data -> 'data-points'->0->>'value' as value
  from mytable t
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(json_value->'tickers') 
  with ordinality as ui(data, idx)
)
select city, store,
  MAX(case when count = 'pudding' then value end) as pudding,
  MAX(case when count = 'cake' then value end) as cake,
  MAX(case when count = 'soda' then value end) as soda,
  MAX(case when count = 'chips' then value end) as chips,
  MAX(case when count = 'soda_machine' then value end) as soda_machine,
  MAX(day) as day
from cte
group by city, store
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/THOAAtlu)